# Hadoop 2.0 Resource Manager high availability

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Hadoop 2.0 provides High Availability with [Federation Architecture](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html). High availability is achieved with above architecture.

I have a doubt regarding "Resource Manager".

> The fundamental idea of MRv2 is to split up the two major functionalities of the JobTracker, resource management and job scheduling/monitoring, into separate daemons. The idea is to have a global ResourceManager (RM) and per-application ApplicationMaster (AM). An application is either a single job in the classical sense of Map-Reduce jobs or a DAG of jobs.
>
> The ResourceManager and per-node slave, the NodeManager (NM), form the data-computation framework. The ResourceManager is the ultimate authority that arbitrates resources among all the applications in the system.

We can have Resource Manager, not co-existing with Name Node. Since we have single resource manager, how the architecture addresses High Availability of resource manager?

What will happen if Resource Manager is down or not available?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Hadoop 2.X.X**, we have **High availability** for both **HDFS** and **YARN**.

**NameNode HA for HDFS high availability.**

**Resource Manager HA (RMHA) for YARN high availability.**

In RMHA, we have one **primary Resource Manager (active)** and one or more **stand by Resource Manager(s)**. This Resource manager HA is coordinated by **Zookeeper**. If active Resource Manager is down, FailoverControl initiates **failover** to make stand by as active Resource Manager. So always we can have **active Resource Manager**. This concept avoids the **Single Point Of Failure (SPOF)** in Yarn Resource Manager.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_hag_rm_ha_config.html#concept_xgs_pc5_vl_unique_1

Answer (score 1):

This has been remedied as of hadoop v2.4+. Take a look [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html).